# Confused between Google's Universal Analytics and Async Analytics. Are we supposed to use both?

Tags: google-analytics

After setting up Google analytics for the first time I went to Admin > Tracking Code:
So apparently this is Universal Analytics given to me.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I can't find my asynchronous tracking code (which would look like this):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

1. Am I only supposed to use one?
2. Do they both go right before `</head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As universal is in beta, I would continue using ga.js tracker on your primary web properties.
If you want to try out the new functions (e.g. custom dimensions/metrics) of Universal, you can create a new property specifically for it.

Also, to simplify deployment, try Google Tag Manager.

Comment: I can't find the async. tracking code though. Admin > Tracking Info > Tracking Code will give me the UA one.

Comment: If you can't see the async tracking code means you have selected Google Universal as the method. In this case, just stick to that tracker and don't worry about the ga.js(async) tracking code.

The GA universal snippet sits just after the opening of the body tag .